# How to load wordpress sidebar using AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using responsive design on my website. Everything is fine except for the fact that on a mobile phone, my website is just too long. There is just too much content for a mobile screen - too much vertical space gets taken up by the sidebar which contains a lot of widgets like popular posts and recent comments and many others.
To make the website smaller, I want the sidebar to not load at all if viewed from a small screen. And I don't want to apply display:hidden to the sidebar container. That would be stupid.

So the most efficient way would be to load the sidebar using AJAX and exclude it if the viewport is less than 800px wide.

Could anybody please tell me if this possible? If this can be done please give some examples and links to some tutorials. I have googled a lot for this but found just one tutorial which I think is not enough as I want to learn from several examples.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) There's tons of resources on using AJAX with WordPress, as well as using JavaScript/jQuery or similar to do client side viewport testing, and WordPress has functions to display sidebars - try putting them together, then ask a question if you have a problem and can't get it to work properly.

Comment: i have'nt tried anything actually. I just need some friendly directions on how this can be done cuz I'm a noob. I will take a look at that wordpress sidebar function and how I can use AJAX on it. Thanks.

Comment: The issue with knowing if the viewport is less than 800px is that you can't know that in advance. I can relate to what you are trying to do, as I often find the sidebar unnecessary bloat for mobile phones. However, technically, Google bots should be fed the same responsive content. The best way may be hiding the sidebar with css media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use WordPress function **[`wp_is_mobile()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)** in your theme, like so

```php
<?php if( !wp_is_mobile() ) get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: The wp_is_mobile function would not do the job for a tablet because full desktop view is desired in landscape mode and mobile view in portrait mode.